# SQL Create a table with one column with incremental counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a table with an incremental counter, let's say from 14 to 17. The table should look like:

```
counter
14
15
16
17
```

Obviously, the range I really need is much larger. Any idea? I use MySQL.

Comment: Like an auto increment field? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following stored procedure. 
(change `t1` to your table name)

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`server`@`%` PROCEDURE `test1`(start_num INT, end_num INT)
 BEGIN

 WHILE start_num < end_num DO
    INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(start_num);
    SET start_num = start_num + 1;
 END WHILE;
 END$$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. This is my first short procedure. I wonder if it is possible using only SQL. (For other non-SP-guys and for me: First create table t1. In my case I had to remove "DEFINER=`semanix`@`%`" otherwise it gives an error (I'm using HeidiSQL). The last "END" should be "END $$" and add "DELIMITER ;" at the end).

Comment: You won't be able to do so without stored procedure since you cannot use WHILE outside of BEGIN / END block.

Answer (score 1):

Create an auto_increment column.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is not that wat I want. I want filling an empty table and not adding a counter when populating a table.

Comment: If you create a table that will auto increment you can pretty easily fill it up with the auto generated number.

Comment: I wonder how I can populate a table with, for example, a counter from 100,010 to 195,020.

Comment: @giordano Use yakiro's solution and pass in start_num = 100,010, end_num = 195,020